# Rotated images comparing

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to find the differences between two images. The program is given 2 pictures as an input. One is original, and the second is slightly modified like this [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mf9r.png) [modified picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtuWW.png)
After comparing the two pictures, the third one is displayed, which shows what is different in the two pictures.[difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HudPt.png).When one of the pictures has a different set of pixels, it's easy to look for differences. But what to do if one of the pictures is rotated literally by 1-2 degrees? Since the search for differences occurs pixel by pixel, that is, each RGB pixel layer is compared, if the image is rotated by 1 degree, the location of the pixels will change and the program will think that the image is completely different and will incorrectly display the differences.[slightly incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPrzg.png). So it's still shows main difference on image, that is hat, bit now you can see the silhouette of tapir, who shouldn't be there. Anny suggestions? I am using opencv and c++

So i tried just to load an image with different rotation angle, but it shows tapir silhouette.

Comment: usual approach: feature matching, Lowe's ratio test (everyone forgets that...), find homography or lesser transform, warp one image into the other's space, do what you already did. -- you **have to** be able to deal with minute pixel differences arising from a simple rescaling of some high-res original picture. you'll see that in any resampling, also any warp of a rotated image.

Comment: new question: https://forum.opencv.org/t/finding-the-difference-between-two-images-one-of-them-is-rotated/11281